# Combine multiple videos using ffmpeg to play back in realtime

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have a situation where I'd like to combine multiple videos that I shot using a camera. The videos are like this:

```
Video 1: 10:00 am - 10:10 am (10 min long)
Video 2: 10:30 am - 11:00 am (30 min long)
Video 3: 11:30 am - 11:45 am (15 min long)
```

Essentially I want to combine them in a way such that I get a 1h45m video file, with blanks in between times that are not recorded. This is to facilitate audio syncing with a track that is recorded separately. So the target video would be:

```
0:00 - 0:10 Video 1
0:10 - 0:30 Black screen
0:30 - 1:00 Video 2
1:00 - 1:30 Black screen
1:30 - 1:45 Video 3
```

One way I thought of doing this is by extracting the timestamps of each video and their duration, calculating the length of the blank video I'd need to stitch them, and then use `concatenate` to combine all the videos. Is there any easier way to do this directly with ffmpeg?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Script: get modified timestamp from input file, get duration, create blank video, concat them.

```
#!/bin/bash
LST=($(ls -1tr video*.mp4))
TOT=${#LST[*]}
f="${LST[0]}"
AGE=$(stat -c %y $f)
SEC=$(date +%s -d"$AGE")
#WID="$(ffprobe -v error -show_entries stream=width -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 "$f" | head -1)"
#HEI="$(ffprobe -v error -show_entries stream=height -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 "$f" | head -1)"
WID=576
HEI=1024
DUR="$(ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=duration -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 "$f")"
DUR="${DUR%.*}"
echo $f $AGE $SEC $DUR "${WID}x${HEI}"
INP=("-i" "$f")
FCT=0
FIL="[0:v][0:a]"

for (( i=1; i<=$(( $TOT -1 )); i++ )); do
  f="${LST[$i]}"
  AGE=$(stat -c %y $f)
  TIM=$(date +%s -d"$AGE")
  ((OFS=TIM-SEC-DUR))
  SEC=$TIM
  BLA="/tmp/blank${i}.mkv"
  ffmpeg -hide_banner -f lavfi -i "color=s=${WID}x${HEI}" -f lavfi -i anullsrc=r=48000 -c:v h264_nvenc -cq 20 -c:a aac -b:a 156k -t "$OFS" -y "$BLA"
  DUR="$(ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=duration -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 "$f")"
  DUR="${DUR%.*}"
  echo $f $AGE $TIM $DUR
  ((FCT+=1))
  INP+=("-i" "$BLA")
  FIL+="[${FCT}:v][${FCT}:a]"
  ((FCT+=1))
  INP+=("-i" "$f")
  FIL+="[${FCT}:v][${FCT}:a]"
done

((FCT+=1))
ffmpeg -hide_banner "${INP[@]}" -filter_complex "
${FIL}concat=n=${FCT}:v=1:a=1[v][a]
" -map [v] -map [a] -c:v h264_nvenc -cq 23 -c:a aac -q:a 4 -y /tmp/output.mkv
vlc /tmp/output.mkv
```

Comment: Thanks! Did you write all this out just for this question?

Comment: @SkeletonBow, yeah, just to keep my brain working.